# Strapi CMS - Headless - two Node instances or in a combined one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi, headless

Using a **headless CMS** for the first time, I would like to know, how I best work with it.

I am using [**Strapi**](https://strapi.io/) as the CMS, where I enter all my content.
Having already set up the website, and it works nicely, currently I am using **two instances of Node.js**.

The **first one** is where strapi (cms) is running.
The **second instance** is where I make my requests to the headless cms, and generate the views based on the returned contents.

**My questions:**

1. Should I try to include the instance which makes the api calls, and generates the views into the same instance, or keep it separated?
2. What is the best practice?
3. How would I best start including my code in the cms, if I would use only one instance? (it seems complicated, while just setting up a new instance is easy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you are meant to use a separate Node Instance.

Comment: Not sure if this counts as an answer... but it kind of solves my question for now.